# AWS API Gateway to SQS - Body Mapping Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, velocity, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to create a proxy for AWS SQS from API Gateway but I am facing difficulties with the Body Mapping Template.

I receive a request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type:
`IDLote=lote434&IDCliente=5&Status=22&Resposta=testmessage`

So I created the following template (to map the form values into a JSON object, to be then serialized into the body of the message - I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it):

```
#set($idLote = "")
#set($idCliente = "")
#set($status = "")
#set($resposta = "")
#foreach( $token in $input.path('$').split('&') )
    #set( $keyVal = $token.split('=') )
    #set( $keyValSize = $keyVal.size() )
    #if( $keyValSize >= 1 )
        #set( $key = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[0]) )
        #if( $keyValSize >= 2 )
            #set( $val = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[1]) )
        #else
            #set( $val = '' )
        #end
        #if( $key == "IDLote" )
            #set($idLote = $val)
        #elseif( $key == "IDCliente" )
            #set($idCliente = $val)
        #elseif( $key == "Status" )
            #set($status = $val)
        #elseif( $key == "Resposta" )
            #set($resposta = $val)
        #end
    #end
#end
#set($event =  "{
  ""idLote"": ""1"",
  ""idCliente"": ""2"",
  ""status"": ""3"",
  ""resposta"": ""434""
}")
Action=SendMessage&MessageGroupId=2&MessageBody=TestMessage
```

After transformation, the body is:
`Action=SendMessage&MessageGroupId=2&MessageBody=TestMessage` as expected (since I'm not using the created JSON).

But I get an error from SQS:
`<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-02-01/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXX/queue-events.fifo is denied.</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId>92f717d8-369c-58c8-abe9-4473b9fb2aab</RequestId></ErrorResponse>`

But if I remove the #foreach from my template and leave it like this:

```
#set($event =  "{
  ""idLote"": ""1"",
  ""idCliente"": ""2"",
  ""status"": ""3"",
  ""resposta"": ""434""
}")
Action=SendMessage&MessageGroupId=2&MessageBody=TestMessage
```

Everything works as expected. The transformed request body is the same as last time, but this time it works.

I have given full access for SQS but I still get the error.

I believe I am doing something wrong, but I couldn't identify what exactly.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SQS error may be caused by an error or an exception in your parsing of the query strings, which happens to be caught otherwise the remaining of the template wouldn't show up, but which generates some kind of additional reporting event.

You could continue your dichotomy to understand which lines does have a problem.

But why are you performing the parsing yourself? You could do:

```
#set($idLote = "$!input.params('IDLote')")
#set($idCliente = "$!input.params('IDCliente')")
#set($status = "$!input.params('Status')")
#set($resposta = "$!input.params('Reposta')")
```

Comment: I performed the parsing because I couldn't get the parameters like you suggested. I tried again now and it didn't work also. Should it work?